# Can Someone Explain or Help me Understand this Public Method in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Can some one help me to understand this bit of code. Which functions are these, why are they used for, what is program flow, and what technique is being used here?

```
public function video($id)
{
    $gdata = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$id."?alt=json";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $gdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($retcode != 200)
    {
        $this->video = FALSE;
        $this->video_id = NULL;
    }else{
        $this->video = json_decode($data);
        $this->video_id = $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: we're not here to teach you php. You can trivially add some echo/var_dump/Print_r calls at various stages to see what the variable's values are.

Comment: Don't be Rude, what am a suppose to ask then , what a fuction do probably i can do that by going to php.net huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it pulls video data from a youtube video. It runs a CURL request and sets the data into $this->video and $this->video_id if the video id exists.